# Multiple subplots in the same figure with networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I'm using matplotlib and networkx to draw networks in python3.
What should I do in order to draw two subplots on the same figure?

Comment: HI Damon, could you please provide an example of your data?

Answer (score 7):

You only need to specify the `ax` parameter of [nx.draw_networkx()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx) (same for the other drawing methods such as `draw_network_nodes`, `draw_network_edges`, etc.).
This allows you to draw the graph in the specified axes.

Consider the following small example.

```
graphs = [nx.gnp_random_graph(20,0.3) for _ in range(4)]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax = axes.flatten()

for i in range(4):
    nx.draw_networkx(graphs[i], ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].set_axis_off()

plt.show()
```

[image]